# Maximum Size of JComponent

Tags: java, swing, dimensions

Is there a hard limit on the size of a JComponent?  I don't mean the one you can set via `setMaximumSize()`.  I mean, is there an absolute limit to how big it's allowed to get?  Every search I do for this just gives me functions to set it, but nothing says anything about how large it can legally get.  All I know is I tried making one at 9000x6000 and it won't draw past a certain value in either dimension.  (It's in a `JScrollPane`.)  I'd like to know what that actual value is.  Is it hardware dependent?  Can I access this value somehow?

Comment: The problem is probably with your code and not the maximum size. You probably didn't override the getPreferredSize() method of your components so the scrollpane isn't working properly. Post your `SSCCE` that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Derp.  Never mind - it was the `BufferedImage` I was using for drawing.  Mind you, 9000x6000 is probably still too large - when I made it large enough it draws, but it's really slow and choppy.  I guess the question then is how to get a very large scrollable image into a Swing app without a major sacrifice in performance...

Comment: It would come down to two factors, Interger.MAX and memory

Comment: Yeah, not getting anywhere near Integer.MAX, fortunately.  Shouldn't be running out of memory either at the sizes I'm getting, but it does impact performance in a major way.  I just wonder if there's an easy way to only keep in memory the part of the JPanel that's currently visible on the screen and not waste cycles thinking about all the stuff you can't currently see.